# Why linker is giving error for global variable in header file

Tags: c++, linker, extern

I have declared a global variable in header.h and included that header in source.cpp and main.cpp but linker is giving error

```
Source.obj : error LNK2005: "int globalVariable" (?globalVariable@@3HA) already defined in     Main.obj
GlobalVariableAndLinkageIssue.exe fatal error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found
```

#### header.h

```
int globalVariable;
```

#### source.cpp

```
#include "header.h"
```

#### main.cpp

```
#include"header.h"

void main() {}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1433204/how-do-i-share-a-variable-between-source-files-in-c-with-extern-but-how

Answer (score 3):

1. Move the declaration to a .cpp file. You can use a declaration in a header file by using:

   `extern int globalVariable; // declaration in header - can have as many as you need`

   But the .cpp file should have the definition:

   `int globalVariable; // definition in .cpp - only need one across all your files`

   C and C++ use textual pre-processor to include headers, this is basically a text insertion, not a smart module system as in some languages. By including it as you were, you are creating multiple definitions, one per .cpp file.
2. As a matter of good practice, you need to get used to using include guards to protect against multiple nested includes (though it would not solve your current issue). If using Visual C++, you can use `#pragma once` or to use a portable solution wrap your header code in:

   `#ifndef _INCLUDE_FOO_H_`

   `#endif`

Answer (score 1):

To create a global variable, you should do the following. Note that in the header, we mark the variable as `extern`, and we actually create the object in a `cpp` file.

#### header.h

```
extern int globalVariable;
```

#### header.cpp

```
#include "header.h"
int globalVariable;
```

#### main.cpp

```
#include "header.h"

int main() {}
```

Answer (score 1):

Put global variable in some .c or .cpp file, so that it can be defined only once and refer in header file using extern
for example,

**header.h**

```
extern int globalVariable;
```

**header.cpp**

```
int globalVariable = 0;
```

**source.cpp**

```
#include "header.h"
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include"header.h"

int main() {
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because BOTH sources #include your header, and thus it is DEFINED twice.

Answer (score -2):

In such situation,it is common to use some #define as follows:

```
//header.h
#ifdef DEFINE_VARS
   #define DEFINE_OR_DECLARE 
#else
   #define DEFINE_OR_DECLARE extern
#endif

DEFINE_OR_DECLARE int globalVariable;


//main.cpp
#define DEFINE_VARS
#include "header.h"
...

//header.cpp
#include "header.h"
...
```

Comment: I would never recommend this.

Comment: Could you kindly explain why?

Comment: Let's say I want to have `globalVariable` have a default value of 4. So I do `DEFINE_OR_DECLARE int globalVariable = 4;`. That will cause warnings that look like: `a.c:1: warning: ‘x’ initialized and declared ‘extern’
`.

Comment: But you would NEVER specify an assignment in such use. This technique is very productive in making sure header files never miss newly introduced var[s]. One then uses an initialization routine in the definition source, to avoid the default value scenario you described.